# Unity "SceneManager.activeSceneChanged" getting called when "LoadSceneAsync" and load other scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

first, there is a singleton object simply is subscribed to `activeSceneChanged`

SomeSingleton.cs

```
void Awake ()
{
    Debug.LogError ("AWAKE");

    if (instance == null) {
        Debug.LogError ("instance == null");

        instance = this;
        MusicController.instance = this;
        SceneManager.activeSceneChanged += OnSceneChanged;
        DontDestroyOnLoad (this.gameObject);
    } else {
        Debug.LogError ("destroy");

        Destroy (this.gameObject);
    }
}


void OnSceneChanged (Scene previousScene, Scene changedScene)
{
    Debug.LogError ("OnSceneChanged changedScene = " + changedScene.name);
}
```

1. from Lobby Scene player moves to Room Scene.
2. in `room scene`.

the "Arena" Scene gets preloaded for better game experience.

```
LoadSceneAsync("Arena")
```

with `allowSceneActivation = false`

when player clicks play button, sets `allowSceneActivation = true`

but when user decides to go back and clicks Leave Button, `LoadScene("Lobby")` gets called.

At this time in console, it will Log

LOGS

```
OnSceneChanged changedScene = Lobby // time : 0.793
OnSceneChanged changedScene = Room // time : 3.982
```

[when player clicks Leave Button]

```
OnSceneChanged changedScene = Arena // time : 7.583
OnSceneChanged changedScene = Lobby // time : 7.583
```

like this...

it just gets activated but wont actually load the scene. why is Arena getting activatd? how to solve this problem???
should i do some `unload` thing to the `AsyncLoading`?

==== EDITED =====

when leave button clicked

```
public void LeaveRoom ()
{
    print ("Leave Room And Move To Lobby");
    SetCanStartIfMasterClient (false);
    PhotonNetwork.LeaveRoom ();
    AdmobController.DestroyBanner ();
    Waiting.instance.StartWaiting (waitingForLeaveRoomData);
    SceneFader.instance.LoadSceneWhenFadingComplete (SceneType.Lobby);
}
```

in SceneFader.cs

```
public enum SceneFadeType
{
    FadeIn = 1,
    FadeOut = -1
}


public class SceneFader : MonoBehaviour
{

    public static SceneFader instance;
    void Awake ()
    {
        instance = this;

        // StartFadeOut
        StartFading (SceneFadeType.FadeOut, null);

    }


    public void LoadSceneWhenFadingComplete (SceneType sceneType)
    {
        // 1. start Fading
        // 2. on fading complete, LoadScene
        StartFading
        (
            fadeType: SceneFadeType.FadeIn,
            onFadingComplete: () => {
                SceneManager.LoadScene (sceneType.ToString ());
            }
        );

    }

    public void LoadSceneWhenFadingCompleteAsync (ScenePreloader scenePreloader)
    {
        // 1 start preloading scene
        // 2 on preloading complete, start fading
        // 3 on fading complete LoadScene


        scenePreloader.AddOnPreloadCompleteAndTriggerIfLoaded (
            onPreloadComplete: () => {
                StartFading (
                    fadeType: SceneFadeType.FadeIn,
                    onFadingComplete: () => {
                        scenePreloader.ActivateSceneWhenReady ();
                    }
                );
            }
        );

    }

    private void StartFading (SceneFadeType fadeType, Action onFadingComplete)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning ("StartFAding ");
        ScreenFader.instance.BeginFade (fadeType, onFadingComplete);
        AudioMasterController.instance.StartFading (fadeType, null);
    }


}
```

in ScenePreloader.cs

```
public class ScenePreloader : MonoBehaviour
{

    Action<float> onPreloadRateChanged;
    Action onPreloadComplete;
    public AsyncOperation sceneLoader;
    public bool isPreloadCompleted;


    public void StartPreloadingScene (SceneType sceneType, LoadSceneMode loadSceneMode, Action<float> onPreloadRateChanged = null, Action onPreloadComplete = null)
    {
        this.onPreloadComplete = onPreloadComplete;
        this.onPreloadRateChanged = onPreloadRateChanged;
        StartCoroutine (PreloadSceneOperation (sceneType, loadSceneMode));
    }


    public IEnumerator PreloadSceneOperation (SceneType sceneType, LoadSceneMode loadSceneMode = LoadSceneMode.Single)
    {
        print ("PreloadSceneOperation sceneType = " + sceneType.ToString ());
        sceneLoader = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync (sceneType.ToString (), loadSceneMode);
        sceneLoader.allowSceneActivation = false;

        while (!sceneLoader.isDone) {
            yield return null;
            if (sceneLoader.progress >= 0.9f) {
                print ("onPreloadComplete");
                isPreloadCompleted = true;
                if (onPreloadComplete != null) {
                    onPreloadComplete ();
                }
                break;
            } else {
                if (onPreloadRateChanged != null) {
                    onPreloadRateChanged (sceneLoader.progress);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void ActivateSceneWhenReady ()
    {

        sceneLoader.allowSceneActivation = true;

    }


    public void AddOnPreloadCompleteAndTriggerIfLoaded (Action onPreloadComplete)
    {
        AddOnPreloadComplete (onPreloadComplete);
        if (isPreloadCompleted) {
            print ("isAlreadyLoadedTrigeringCallback");
            onPreloadComplete ();
        }
    }

    public void AddOnPreloadComplete (Action onPreloadComplete)
    {
        this.onPreloadComplete += onPreloadComplete;
    }

    public void SetOnLoadProgressValueChanged (Action<float> onLoadProgressValueChanged)
    {
        this.onPreloadRateChanged = onLoadProgressValueChanged;
    }


}
```

Comment: Where and how you 'preload' Arena?
Does it exactly print both records after LoadSceneAsync("Loby")? maybe it's from 'preloading'?

Comment: yes, it does exactly print both records after LoadScene("Loby") // not Async

Comment: @Shakra i updated the question

Comment: Show the button code.

Comment: try to use "SceneManager.sceneLoaded += ...." (or check AsyncOperation.IsDone that you get from LoadSceneAsync) to check when Lobby loaded and activate it with "SceneManager.SetActiveScene()"

Comment: @Shakra i think this is an unity's internal error..

Comment: @Draco18s updated the button behind code.

Comment: Some posts on unity's forums told that when you async load scene with 'allowSceneActivation=false' this break loading scene pipeline, this might be a problem source. Btw loading scene with async, still might freeze you main thread, because it's still runs on main thread.

Comment: @Shakra so... no alternatives?

Comment: Last suggestion is to post this question on main forum. 
Sorry but I don't have any more ideas why it doesn't work.